# Dns error with www

Tags: web, dns, nameservers

I set up my DNS and when I tried to got to the www.mypage.com it was not found. but mypage.com does work. I've set the `www` and `start` to Cnames pointing to the Nameserver but that doesnt work here's a screen shot of my DNS http://scooop.webatu.com/Screen%20Shot%202012-03-25%20at%2012.37.31%20PM.png

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start and www should be CNAME and point to main domain or @.

Answer (score 2):

**CNAMEs** 'www' and 'start' should point to **mypage.com**. not **ns1.domaincontrol.com**